# String not concatenating as I would expect

Tags: c#, string

I just don't get why the following statement is not evaluating as I would expect.

With `UserFirstName` set to "Joe" and `UserLastName` set to "Plumber", `SpeakerName` is getting just "Joe".

```
spr.SpeakerName = presenterRec.UserFirstName ?? "" + " " + 
    presenterRec.UserLastName ?? "";
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Personally, I'd use string.Format anyway - `spr.SpeakerName = string.Format("{0} {1}", presenterRec.UserFirstName ?? "", presenterRec.UserLastName ?? "");` or even as @CompuChip points out `spr.SpeakerName = string.Format("{0} {1}", presenterRec.UserFirstName, presenterRec.UserLastName);`

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. I recently answered it on the Coverity development testing blog: http://blog.coverity.com/2013/10/23/oct-23-post-c-static-values/  Note that the blog software was updated this week and some of the markup is still wrong on this page; I'll fix it later this week.

Comment: Also, concatenating null is automatically the same as concatenating the empty string, so none of this code is necessary.

Comment: You might want to ditch the space when one or more names is null or empty:
`spr.SpeakerName = (presenterRec.UserFirstName + " " + presenterRec.UserLastName).Trim();`

Answer (score 14):

Because if `presenterRec.UserFirstName` is not null you get that value and the evaluation of your expression stops there.

In other words, you have an order-of-operations problem. Try this:

```
spr.SpeakerName = (presenterRec.UserFirstName ?? "") 
                  + " " +  
                  (presenterRec.UserLastName ?? "");
```

[The Operator ?? reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: ah, of course.  thanks, adding some parens (I'd accept your answer but SO insists you could not have solved it so fast)

Answer (score 5):

The null-coalescing operator has pretty low precedence, as documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

The solution, as mentioned, is adding parentheses

```
(presenterRec.UserFirstName ?? "") 
            + " " + 
            (presenterRec.UserLastName ?? "")
```

However, in string concatenation in .NET the null string is treated as an empty string, so actually

```
presenterRec.UserFirstName + " " + presenterRec.UserLastName
```

would also work in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks CompuChip, I was skeptical of not using ?? but just tested it and works as you say.  Now, I'm wanting all the time back that I've put into coding over the past 10 years all those null checks on strings.  I totally expected that any null string in a concat would kill the result.  I wonder if everyone but me knows this.